# present continuous in this case

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

I am flying to Spain tomorrow and **am staying/will stay** there one week.

What is the best solution I think both are valid.

Comment: As you say, they're both fine.

Comment: Really idiomatic and really how people say this: ***I'm flying*** to Spain tomorrow and am staying there a week.

Comment: @Lambie: "and staying" instead of "and am staying" would sound much more natural.

Comment: @Robusto: I was just going to suggest that. Conjunction reduction is one of the reasons for repeating a structure.

Comment: There are many possibilities. It's fine to repeat the auxiliary. Just as "natural".

Answer (score 1):

In your example, since the occurrence is soon

> I am flying to Spain tomorrow and **staying for a** week.
>   I am flying to Spain tomorrow and **will stay** in Madrid for **a** week.

otherwise, you might use

> I am flying to Spain *for Christmas* and **will be staying for a** week.
>   I am flying to Spain *for Christmas* and **am staying** with my brother.

Using either of your choices would be understood.